# Python package binaries installation on MacOSX

Tags: macos, python

I'm using the built-in python from OSX 10.8, but when I install a new package with `pip` or `easy_install` a bin executable is created on `/usr/local/bin`

There is a way to configuration a new location?

I'm using brew (unless python) and python package is installed with root privileges and I want to separate this python package bin.

Comment: What do you mean "you're using brew and package is installed with root privileges"? If you're using Homebrew's Python and use `pip` or `easy_install` from `/usr/local/bin`, these won't interfere with your system installations and are *not* installed with root privileges. Homebrew doesn't run as root.

Comment: I'm using brew, but python is actually not installed via brew and when I want to install it using brew the "linkage" won't work because "Possible conflicting files are: /usr/local/bin/pip-2.7 ..."